# How do I fix React ' is not defined no-undef'?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a detailed view for each movie in a list of movies. I have Django as backend and React as frontend.

When I am trying to make a detailed view for each movie I get an error.

Error log:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/movie-list.js
  Line 5:26:  'movie' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 6:28:  'movie' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I have tried to bind but don't fully understand where the problem is.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MovieList from "./components/movie-list";

  componentDidMount() {
    //fetch data
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Token 8588cb6fcc2ee0bf9915d4c6b720554347d5883f'
      }
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ movies: res }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }

  movieClicked = movie => {
    console.log(movie);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Movie Rater</h1>
            <MovieList movies={this.state.movies} movieClicked={this.movieClicked}/>
            <MovieDetails movie={this.state.selectedMovie}/>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**movie-list.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function MovieList(props) {

    const movieClicked = movie = evt => {
        props.movieClicked(movie);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {props.movies.map(movie => {
                return (
                    <h3 key={movie.id} onClick={movieClicked(movie)}>
                        {movie.title}
                    </h3>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MovieList;
```

I want to make the detailed view work.

Comment: can you show a snippet of code for the file movie-list.js?

Comment: @harisu Yes I added it :)

Comment: @Poenix1355 answer is good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referring to a variable that's outside the scope in the method `movieClicked`. Change it to:

```
const movieClicked = (movie) => {
    props.movieClicked(movie);
}
```

Edit:

As some of the people in the comments are pointing out, the simplified solution would be:

```
import React from 'react';

function MovieList(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.movies.map(movie => {
                return (
                    <h3 key={movie.id} onClick={() => props.movieClicked(movie)}>
                        {movie.title}
                    </h3>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MovieList;
```

Comment: Or missing half an arrow `const movieClicked = movie => evt => {
    props.movieClicked(movie);
}`

Comment: Couldn't he/she just use onClick={props.movieClicked(movie)} without defining a second movieClicked function?

Comment: @giuseppedeponte I don't think that would work. Doing it like that would make the `movieClicked` method return another function, which wouldn't get executed unless he did something like `movieClicked(movie)()`.

Comment: The click event handler just pass a DOM event as argument, not a movie

Comment: that will work if he does onClick={() => props.movieClicked(movie)}  directly

Comment: @Phoenix1355 Look at how the onClick prop is passed. The first function is called there. The returned function will be called on click event

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work because your movie variable (inside the fucntion) hold the function refrence (same function) and not the variable you are passing, check the example here (you can test it to understand the issue)

```
const movieClicked = movie = evt => {
    console.log(movie); //shows a function 
    console.log(evt); // shows the actual value (movie123)
}
movieClicked("movie123"); // work
movie("movie123");// work
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
const a = b = 5;
```

here you get as a result a = 5 and b = 5, in your case movieClicked = movie , both holds the a function as a value.
as suggested by Phoenix1355 this code will work

```
const movieClicked = (movie) => {
  props.movieClicked(movie);
}
```

and also this one will work (doen't make sense in this case but you may encouter this again some day)

```
const movieClicked = movie = evt => {
    props.movieClicked(evt);
}
```